# Bones and weighted mesh parts disappear in object and pose mode

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

The bones in my project disappear when in pose and object mode, along with part of the mesh weighted to their respective bones. They aren't marked as hidden, and I couldn't find them in any other layers.

The bones affected by this are on the pinky finger of the right hand in the blend file below:

.blend file for anyone who wants to see the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihh6vx4y0nd6836/m950a_anims.blend?dl=0

Comment: what are the concerned bone names?

Comment: the bones are ValveBiped.Bip01_R_Finger41 and 42

Comment: You scaled those bones down. Select every bones by hitting "A" and press "Alt+S" To reset their scale.

Comment: ohhh, I honestly don't remember ever scaling any bones, but that solved the issue - thanks a bunch!